# Why is char* not copying into the vector but string is copied?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, char

Okay, I'm trying to figure out an issue, when I try this code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<char*> v;
    char s[10];
    std::cout << "Enter Values :\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        cin >> s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\nPrinted Values :\n";
    for (auto ss : v){
        cout << ss << "\n";
        cout << "------------\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I received:

```
Enter Values :
aaaa
ssss
ddddd
ffff
errrr



Printed Values :
errrr
------------
errrr
------------
errrr
------------
errrr
------------
errrr
------------
```

But now I changed "char*" to "string":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<string> v;
    string s;
    std::cout << "Enter Values :\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        cin >> s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\nPrinted Values :\n";
    for (auto ss : v){
        cout << ss << "\n";
        cout << "------------\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it stores all of it into the vector:

```
Enter Values :
aaaa
ssss
ddddd
ffff
errrr



Printed Values :
aaaa
------------
ssss
------------
ddddd
------------
ffff
------------
errrr
------------
```

My question, is why char* doesn't get stored in the vector but string is being stored in the vector ?

Comment: `char*` is only a pointer while `std::string` is a class. Arrays aren't copied automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a vector of char* will store character pointers (memory addresses of the first char of your character array s), not the characters themselves. The only place that stores the chars is your array s itself. But that's continuously overwritten by the <<. Since s is defined only once, it has only one, unique address, and your whole vector will just contain pointers with that same address value.

Note that in C++ the name of an array (also a char array) is converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: "Note that in C++ the name of an array (also a char array) IS a pointer to its first element" No. It is converted to such a pointer in most contexts, but it is not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, seems I'm about to learn something here. Converted as in "value changed in memory", or "type interpreted differently"?

Comment: It will have both a different value and different type after the conversion. Nothing in memory is necessarily changed, since the result of the value is not an lvalue. The simplest example of the differentation is `sizeof`: `sizeof(arrayname)` gives the size of the _whole_ array; if `arrayname` was a pointer, then it would give the size of a pointer. So `arrayname` actually refers to the entire array; it is converted to be a pointer that array if you use it in a context which requires that (according to the language rules). (In this case "converted" does not mean that the original is changed).

Comment: Can't upvote until the criminally incorrect statement _"in C++ the name of an array (also a char array) IS a pointer to its first element."_ is removed.

Comment: Well, now you can ;)